# How to create downloadable file api with vertx in memory files

Tags: java, vert.x

Iam download files from S3 and keep them in memory by converting it to byte array.
I dont understand how can I take this byte array and create a download api using vertx.

here is where I stuck:

```
    router.get("/api/download/:requestId").handler(this::downloadFile);

private void downloadSimulatorFile(RoutingContext routingContext) {
            String requestId = routingContext.request().getParam("requestId");
            JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
            try {
               byte [] array=downloadFileFromS3ByRequestId(requestId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e);

            } finally {
                routingContext.response()
                        .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                          .sendFile(..)
                   // here is where i stuck as sendFile only expects 
              Strings which symol path to a file

            }
    }
```

How can I modify this without saving the file and keep it in-memory?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you convert your download file into stream and send that stream in response.

Comment: any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it, and it works:

```
req.response()
  .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .end(Buffer.buffer(bytes));
```

Answer (score 1):

**For sending xlsx file as byte Array in vertx**

```
byte [] array=downloadFileFromS3ByRequestId(requestId);     
response.putHeader(io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=file.xlsx");
response.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
response.end(Buffer.buffer(array));
```